# wskdebug fails with ECONNREFUSED

Tags: openwhisk

I have a local dev environment of adobe aio services running. According to adobes docs wskdebug should be used to debug locally. When I try to use wsk debug either through the cli or vscode I get this error:

```
FetchError: request to http://0.0.0.0:56260/init failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 0.0.0.0:56260
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/Users/<username>/Documents/Repos/<reponame>/node_modules/node-fetch/lib/index.js:1501:11)
    at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:519:28)
    at Socket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:495:9)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:519:28)
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:169:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:128:3)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  type: 'system',
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED'
}
```

The port changes each time.

I have tried checking for firewall issues and also tried running on my personal pc to see if there was an issue with corporate security on my work laptop but got the same error. In orbstack I see a container spin up when I run the wskdebug command but it immediately closes so I'm thinking there may be an issue there. I have tried getting the logs for the container but there are no errors or anything else in the logs. I have also tried using docker desktop in place of orbstack with the same results.

I would like to get wskdebug up and running so we can debug our code locally.

Answer (score 0):

`0.0.0.0` is a special IP address that tells a server that it can bind to any network interface. You can't connect an http client like the wskcli to this address.

If you are trying to connect to a container deployed locally. Then the IP address you will want to use is called the *loopback* address. Which is `127.0.0.1`.